# Confusing call sequence in scala recursion

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to trace recursion processing in scala. The following is the code sample:

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int =
  if (n <= 1) 1
  else {
    println("Computing factorial of " + n + " - I first need factorial of " + (n-1))
    def result = n * factorial(n - 1)
    println("Computed factorial of " + n)
    result
  }
println(factorial(3))
```

The following is the output:

```
Computing factorial of 3 - I first need factorial of 2
Computed factorial of 3
Computing factorial of 2 - I first need factorial of 1
Computed factorial of 2
6
```

And it is pretty strange because parameter `n` cannot be computed before parameter `n-1`. I would rather expect the following output:

```
Computing factorial of 3 - I first need factorial of 2
Computing factorial of 2 - I first need factorial of 1
Computed factorial of 2
Computed factorial of 3
6
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you expect would be for the following program:

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int =
  if (n <= 1) 1
  else {
    println("Computing factorial of " + n + " - I first need factorial of " + (n-1))
    val result = n * factorial(n - 1) // here is the difference def -> val
    println("Computed factorial of " + n)
    result
  }
println(factorial(3))
```

Beetween prints you're defining a function:

```
def result = n * factorial(n - 1)
```

but it does not mean you're invoking it. Function (`def`) is lazily evaluated, whereas value (`val`) - eagerly. It's only a definition. Afterwards you proceed to the second `println` and on `result`, where the value is returned the `result` function is invoked yielding print statements for `n - 1`.

Answer (score -2):

## Recursion is cool, tail recursion is better.

```scala
def factorial(n: Long): Long = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(fact: Long, n: Long): Long = {
    if (n < 2) fact * n
    else go(fact * n, n - 1)
  }
  if (n == 0) 1 else go(1, n)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly answer for OP's question he is asking for the reason why his code is not working as expected, he is not looking for alternative or better solution.